# Регулярное выражение для разбора xml подобного bb_code

Tags: парсер, bbcode

Требуется регулярное выражение для разбора bbcode xml подобного текста, не стандартный bbcode вида [x=y]z[/x] , а как бы формата xml : [x y="z" a="b"][/x]

Вот это выражение

```
 $regex = '#\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9_]+)="(.*?)"\](((?R)|.)*?)\[\/\1]#is'
```

находит тег x , текст между тегами и находит один атрибут  потому что захватывает все что находится между двумя крайними ковычками в открывающем теге. Нужно получит весь массив атрибутов в дополнении к тегу и тексту между тегами.

Comment: Не уверен, что это справедливо и для этой задачи но говорят, что xml, html не стоит и пытаться разбирать регулярными выражениями.

Comment: да я так подумал регулярное выражение находит совпадения, но вот с извлечение переменных - это несколько иная задача: мне фактически как я понимаю, надо разбить регвыражение на две части.